# ORA-00933 sql command not properly ended ( in insert query )

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want the following query to be executed but I get an error:

```
insert into personal_info (case_type) 
values ('unknown') 
where case_description like '%normal%';
```

But when I am running the following query I get no errors:

```
select * 
from personal_info 
where case_description like '%normal%';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not `INSERT` you're looking for, but `UPDATE`:

```
update personal_info set 
  case_type = 'unknown'
  where case_description like '%normal%';
```

---

If it were `insert`, then you'd just

```
insert into personal_info (case_type) values ('unknown');
```

as `insert` - using `values` - can't contain a `where` clause.